# Vuejs does' nt work using cdn

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new to `VueJS`, but something is not working using CDN. 
I am using a simple example but still doesn't evaluate string interpolation.
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vue</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
       <p>{{ message }}</p>       
    </div>   
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue'></script>
    <script src='vue.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Vuejs**

```
   var app = new Vue({
     e1:'#app',
     data:{
       message:'Hello Vue!'
     }
   })
```

**OUTPUT**

[It is showing {{message}} instead of Hello Vue!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5iVL.png)

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: `e1` => `el` it's typo

Comment: e1 => el as in **el**ement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app', /* NOT e1 */
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/vue'></script>
<script src='vue.js'></script>
```

You should change `e1` to `el`.

JUST typo...

Comment: if not e1, than what ? typo?? @bugraiser

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman Not e1 its e as an elephant and l as lucas : el

Comment: thanks, it works, sometimes a single mistake brainstorms me!